# How do I create a Angular 7 beta project?

Tags: angular, angular7

Apologize for the super basic question, but what's the proper way to create a Angular 7 beta project?

Can you do so with the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just needed to use `npm install @angular/core@next @angular/commmon@next @angu.... etc`

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming that you already have Node and NPM installed.

If you are on **Windows** you have to do:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@next
```

On **Mac** or **Linux**:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@next
```

This will install globally the next version of Angular CLI which is at this time version 7.0.0-beta.4.This might change depending on the project development.
Check out [this link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli) to keep up with the project evolution.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Angular 7** has been just released.

### Update z cli

`ng update @angular/cli @angular/core`

then u hv sucessfully upgraded to angular 7;

`ng new my-first-project`